# Random Signal Energy

Tags: random-process, signal-power, stochastic, signal-energy

Why the energy of random signal(random process) is infinite? and why random signal can not be zero at infinity?
I know that there is a relation between the tow questions but I'am still confused.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the energy of random signal(random process) is infinite?

It's not. Unless your random process is defined that way!

What you're probably forgetting is to state a property of the random process. For example, if the process is *stationary*, then the variance and mean, hence the expected power, need to be constant for all points in time; if you have non-zero power for ever, and then integrate over time to get the energy, you'll see your energy diverges, necessarily.

> why random signal can not be zero at infinity?

That wording is ... interesting.

"To have a value at infinity" is usually something that we apply to convergent sequences or functions. So to even be able to say which value something has "at infinity" ($\infty$ is *not* a number at which you can "look at" a signal or a function over time), you need that to converge.

Many random signals do converge to zero, so this statement is wrong; maybe you're also missing stationarity?

Comment: Sorry I didn't made my question clear, so yes it is stationary, but why it should have a constant power, and why it cannot be zero?

Comment: Because power is the sum of variance and the square of the mean. And these two are constant because that's literally in the definition of "stationary".

Comment: So if we have an infinite energy we pass to power, and what made energy infinite is that the values are not tend to zero, is what am I saying right?

Comment: "we have an infinite energy we pass to power": I don't understand this. What do you mean?

Comment: I don't know I am confused, so let me say that if we have a finite power so the energy is infinite, so what I didn't realy understand that how a random signal would not tend to zero and how that will make the energy infinite.

Comment: "We have finite power so the energy is infinite": Zero power is finite and it can lead to finite energy, so you're mixing things up in your head, I guess.

Comment: I got that, so non-zero give us a infinite energy

Comment: good. But that is not special about random signals. I don't understand why you assume a random signal would tend to zero?

Comment: Yes I understand the point that it's not only for random signals, I specified my question for stationary random signals becaus I found that they have infinite energy and I didn't understand it's relation with tending to zero.

Comment: a stationary signal can't tend to zero, because that implies the variance changes.